# Read url line by line in python

Tags: python

I have a list containing url of images. I want to read the images in each url line by line using python. I have tried different ways, but could only read one line.

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: code:                                                                                                                        fd = urllib.urlopen("first url")
 image_file = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
 img = Image.open(image_file)

Comment: Post the code _in your question_* (as you see, it's not readable at all here).

Answer (score 0):

Not having seen your code, but I would recommend using [Requets](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

In a shell I did:

```
pip install --user requests
```

to get the above module.

If you have an url you would be able to perform in an interactive Python

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_static/requests-sidebar.png")
```

And to examine the content of the image:

```
print r.content
```

**Beware** the above prints the binary content to your console.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your code will only read one url. What I have is a dataset containing thousands of url. I want to read each line at time.

Comment: I'd be glad to help further. The code you posted will only download one URL if succesful. Is your dataset an array? You'll probably have to create a loop for that.